# Passing a viewbag to a @Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to pass view bag to a DropDownList but is not working.

**Dropdownlist Error**

[image]

view

```
   <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BanhoTosaId, "BanhoTosaId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
               @Html.DropDownList("TransporteId", ViewBag.BanhoTosaId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BanhoTosaId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Controller

```
 // GET: AgendaBTs/Create
        public ActionResult Create(int id, int pet)
        {

            ViewBag.BanhoTosaId = new SelectList(db.BanhoTosas, "BanhoTosaId", "Tipo");
            ViewBag.ClienteId = new SelectList(db.Clientes, "ClienteId", "Nome", id);
            ViewBag.PetId = new SelectList(db.Pets, "PetId", "PetNome", pet);
            ViewBag.TransporteId = new SelectList(db.Transportes, "TransporteId", "Tipo");

            if (ViewBag.BanhoTosaId != null && ViewBag.SelectedValue != null)
            {
                BanhoTosa BT = db.BanhoTosas.Find(ViewBag.BanhoTosaId);
                Transporte TS = db.Transportes.Find(ViewBag.TransporteId);
                decimal valorSoma = BT.Valor + TS.Valor;
                ViewBag.Total = valorSoma;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Total = 0;
            }

            return View();
        }
```

If I let the dropdown this way  @Html.DropDownList("TransporteId",null, htm....
the if in the controller you throw the else method.

How can i do to solve this?

Comment: What in the world are you trying to do here? What is the point of `if (ViewBag.BanhoTosaId != null && ViewBag.SelectedValue != null)` since you just set them and they can never be `null`

Comment: First you need to cast the SelectList in your method - `@Html.DropDownList("TransporteId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.BanhoTosaId` ... }` but that makes no sense since you trying to bind to `TransporteId`, not `BanhoTosaId`. But then that will not work either (start by reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161202/can-the-viewbag-name-be-the-same-as-the-model-property-name-in-a-dropdownlist) to understand. Stop using view bag and use a view model

Answer (score 4):

you first need to make a list from data you wanna fill list by it like that :

```
List<Category> CatList = db.Categories.ToList();
```

and then use a ViewBag :

```
 ViewBag.CategoriesList = new SelectList(CatList, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
```

after that you will going to view and write:

```html
     <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:85px">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryID, ViewBag.CategoriesList as SelectList,
             "Select Category", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                  
                    </div>
                </div>
```

this example from project i worked on it before

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the ViewBag.BanhoTosaId:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("TransporteId", (List<SelectList>) ViewBag.BanhoTosaId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**OR**

In your `Create` action replace this:

```
ViewBag.TransporteId = new SelectList(db.Transportes, "TransporteId", "Tipo");
```

By

```
 ViewBag.TransporteId = db.Transportes;
```

Add then in your razor view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("TransporteId", new SelectList(ViewBag.TransporteId , "TransporteId", "Tipo"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
 @Html.DropDownList("TransporteId", ViewBag.BanhoTosaId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

with

```
@Html.DropDownList("TransporteId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.BanhoTosaId,null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```